# Trying to use str_match() to identify some numbers in text

Tags: r, stringr

Just need some help extracting the 'Batting number', runs scored and balls faced as separate columns. I know i can use str_match() function to get this done. Any help will be much appreciated?

Batting at number 6, scored 38 runs from 102 balls including 2 fours and 1 sixes.

Batting at number 11, scored 5 runs from 9 balls including 1 fours and 0 sixes.

Batting at number 7, scored 9 runs from 24 balls including 1 fours and 0 sixes.

Batting at number 10, scored 14 runs from 11 balls including 3 fours and 0 sixes.

Batting at number 1, scored 5 runs from 19 balls including 0 fours and 0 sixes.

Batting at number NA, scored NA including NA fours and NAs

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups to capture the text that you are interested in :

```
data <- stringr::str_match(x, 'Batting at number (\\d+), scored (\\d+) runs from (\\d+) balls')[, -1]
data <- type.convert(data.frame(data), as.is = TRUE)
names(data) <- c('batting_number', 'runs_scored', 'balls_faced')
data

#  batting_number runs_scored balls_faced
#1              6          38         102
#2             11           5           9
#3              7           9          24
#4             10          14          11
#5              1           5          19
#6             NA          NA          NA
```

---

In base R, we can use `strcapture` which does all of the above in one step :

```
data <- strcapture('Batting at number (\\d+), scored (\\d+) runs from (\\d+) balls', x, 
           proto = list(batting_number = numeric(), runs_scored = numeric(),balls_faced = numeric()))
```

**data**

```
x <- c("Batting at number 6, scored 38 runs from 102 balls including 2 fours and 1 sixes.", 
"Batting at number 11, scored 5 runs from 9 balls including 1 fours and 0 sixes.", 
"Batting at number 7, scored 9 runs from 24 balls including 1 fours and 0 sixes.", 
"Batting at number 10, scored 14 runs from 11 balls including 3 fours and 0 sixes.", 
"Batting at number 1, scored 5 runs from 19 balls including 0 fours and 0 sixes.", 
"Batting at number NA, scored NA including NA fours and NAs")
```